# Can't debug powershell script using command line

Tags: powershell, debugging, command-line, terminal

I would like to debug a script I wrote in powershell using the command line debugger (not powershell ISE). I wrote a simple script, saved as a ps1 file and then ran the following commands in my terminal:

- `set-psbreakpoint -script test.ps1 -line 8`
- .\test.ps1

I got the following output:

```
Hit Line breakpoint on 'test.ps1:8'

At test.ps1:8 char:3
+   cat $py_file.fullname
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Then the debugger exits and I am unable to debug my file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the debugger works fine, the issue is that I have oh-my-posh installed and have customized my terminal. I think oh-my-posh is hiding the `[DBG]` prefix. I will log an issue with oh-my-posh.